# Use JNI to Create, Populate and Return a Java Class Instance

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use a JNI function to create a Java class and set some properties of that class using the DeviceId.java constructor method.  I'm able to get the constructor method using the GetMethodID, but how would I create a new instance of Device.java and then set the properties (setId and setCache).  The goal is to return a fully populated instance of Device.java Object to the caller.  Any ideas?

**JNI Function:**

```
 JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_test_getID(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) 
    {
        jmethodID cnstrctr;
        jclass c = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/test/DeviceId");
        if (c == 0) {
            printf("Find Class Failed.\n");
         }else{
            printf("Found class.\n");
         }

        cnstrctr = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;[B)V");
        if (cnstrctr == 0) {
            printf("Find method Failed.\n");
        }else {
            printf("Found method.\n");
        }

        return (*env)->NewObject(env, c, cnstrctr);
    }
```

**Java Class:**

```
package com.test;

public class DeviceId {
    private String id;
    private byte[] cache;

        public DeviceId(){}
    public DeviceId(String id, byte[] cache){
        this.id=id;
        this.cache=cache;
    }

    public byte[] getCache() {
        return cache;
    }

    public void setCache(byte[] cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the `"[B"` in `"(Ljava/lang/String;[B)V"`?

Comment: @WilburWhateley, it's an [array of bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30815321/4440694)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you called `GetMethodID`, you provided the signature for the two-arg constructor.  Thus, you just need to pass your `jstring` and a `jbytearray` when you call `NewObject` - for example:

```
return (*env)->NewObject(env, c, cnstrctr, id, cache);
```

You don't need to call the `setId` and `setCache` methods unless you decide to call the 0-arg constructor - and that just complicates your code since you'll have to call `GetMethodID` for those and call them.  Simpler to continue down the route you're on.

Comment: Should there be a NewGlobalRef since it would go out of scope when we return.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to return a **custom** Java object from **JNI's cpp code** back to Java. The solution is to return a `jobject` from cpp function and use our custom Java object in native method declaration.

```
public class PyError {

    public String message;

    public boolean occurred;

    public PyError(boolean occurred, String message){
        this.message = message;
        this.occurred = occurred;
    }
}
```

and method declaration in Java:

```
native PyError nativePythonErrorOccurred();
```

on the cpp side:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_your_package_nativePythonErrorOccurred(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    jclass javaLocalClass = env->FindClass("com/your/package/PyError");

    if (javaLocalClass == NULL) {
        LOGP("Find Class Failed.\n");
    } else {
        LOGP("Found class.\n");
    }

    jclass javaGlobalClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(javaLocalClass));

    // info: last argument is Java method signature
    jmethodID javaConstructor = env->GetMethodID(javaGlobalClass, "<init>", "(ZLjava/lang/String;)V");

    if (javaConstructor == NULL) {
        LOGP("Find method Failed.\n");
    } else {
        LOGP("Found method.\n");
    }

    jobject pyErrorObject = env->NewObject(javaGlobalClass, javaConstructor, true, env->NewStringUTF("Sample error body"));
    return pyErrorObject;
}
```

Determine the signature of the method using
`javap -s java.your.package.YourClass`. 
Also, have a look [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html).

If you encounter error similar to: `JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale Global 0xf2ac01ba` your method signature is wrong, you're passing wrong arguments to `env->NewObject()` or you're not using global state of jni objects - more [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html).