# NDK with JNI while calling method with a return type non primitive

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I need a mapping between c structure and java class model. reason is that i want to call a method of c which is returning a structure for which i have model class in java. I have successfully called native method with primitive data types or void from Java code. but not with any object for my case AlacFile or just Object obj.
see code for what i am saying.

c code...

```
alac_file * Java_org_phlo_AirReceiver_AirReceiver_create_alac2(JNIEnv* env,
      jclass thiz, int samplesize, int numchannels) {

return create_alac(samplesize, numchannels);
}

alac_file *create_alac(int samplesize, int numchannels){
   alac_file *newfile = (alac_file*)malloc(sizeof(alac_file));

   newfile->samplesize = samplesize;
   newfile->numchannels = numchannels;
   newfile->bytespersample = (samplesize / 8) * numchannels;

   return newfile;
}
```

i have a structure for alac_file defined in c class.

and I am calling this method from java as follows.

```
public native AlacFile create_alac2(int samplesize , int numchannels );
```

Output;

Compiled successfullly and run.

Received a crash when this above native method called. crash is as follows.

```
    01-28 03:51:56.202: I/AirReceiver(31668): Registered AirTunes service           '08606EB2F10B@localhost (p2p0)' on fe80::860:6eff:feb2:f10b%p2p0/fe80::860:6eff:feb2:f10b%p2p0%5
01-28 03:51:56.212: I/System.out(31668): Loading libraray BEFORE 1111
01-28 03:51:56.212: D/dalvikvm(31668): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.airreceiver-1/libhairtunes.so 0x4212dad0
01-28 03:51:56.232: D/dalvikvm(31668): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.airreceiver-1/libhairtunes.so 0x4212dad0
01-28 03:51:56.232: D/dalvikvm(31668): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.airreceiver-1/libhairtunes.so 0x4212dad0, skipping init
01-28 03:51:56.232: I/System.out(31668): Loading libraray AFTER 1111
01-28 03:51:56.232: W/dalvikvm(31668): No implementation found for native Lorg/phlo/AirReceiver/AirReceiver;.create_alac2:(II)Lcom/beatofthedrum/alacdecoder/AlacFile;
01-28 03:51:56.242: W/dalvikvm(31668): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419d6700)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.phlo.AirReceiver.AirReceiver.create_alac2:(II)Lcom/beatofthedrum/alacdecoder/AlacFile;
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at org.phlo.AirReceiver.AirReceiver.create_alac2(Native Method)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at org.phlo.AirReceiver.AirReceiver.main(AirReceiver.java:461)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at com.example.droidairplayandroid.MainActivity$AirServerAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at com.example.droidairplayandroid.MainActivity$AirServerAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-28 03:51:56.252: E/AndroidRuntime(31668):  ... 4 more
01-28 03:51:56.282: I/Process(31668): Sending signal. PID: 31668 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You are likely going to either need to parse the C structures in Java as direct Byte (or whatever) buffers, or else use so-called "reverse" JNI calls from C to create and manipulate the elements of Java objects.

Comment: @ChrisStratton as i found crash as native method not found.I'll try reverse jni call .but can u please also guide me for the way u are saying about parse the C structures in Java as direct Byte (or whatever) buffers as don't get it properly.

Comment: Read the documentation on ByteBuffer.  Your crash is likely something trivial and unrelated to this functional challenge, such as a naming problem or even a build problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your method signature is careting problem.

```
public native AlacFile create_alac2(int samplesize , int numchannels );
```

Try once,

```
public native AlacFile createAlac2(int samplesize , int numchannels );//remove '-' here
```

May be its splitting create and alac2.

Answer (score 2):

You must define your function to return **jobject**. Use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130976/192373) to create in C a new instance of Java object, populate it, and return to Java.

Comment: i have tried with jobject as well. but then caught with error as Ljava.lang.Object.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Try to follow the example I linked.

Comment: helped me in calling other similar functions.