# What's "Method Signature" parameter when calling a Java method using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface, signature

I want to call an Android Java method using JNI in Qt. There is a weird "Method Signature" parameter that I cannot understand. What's this and how should I set it?

In examples it's something like `(II)I` or `(I)I`. What does it mean?

For example:

```
jint max = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("java/lang/Math", "max", "(II)I", a, b);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is all explained in the docs. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

```
Type Signature   Java Type
Z                boolean
B                byte
C                char
S                short
I                int
J                long
F                float
D                double
L fully-qualified-class ;   fully-qualified-class
[ type           type[]
( arg-types ) ret-type method type
```

Your `(II)I` is a method taking two integers as arguments and returning an int. E.g. `int m(int i, int j)`.

A method `void print(String message)` would be `(Ljava/lang/String;)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. (II)I looks simple now. but what's (Ljava/lang/String;) ? I cannot understand this signature.

Comment: @rostamiani  L is indicating a complete class name. `;` is needed to signal the end of the class name.  And of course String is short for java.lang.String.