# JNI signature of non-packaged objects

Tags: java, java-native-interface

according to the doc:

> The name argument is a fully-qualified class name or an array type
>   signature . For example, the fully-qualified class name for the
>   java.lang.String class is:
>    "java/lang/String"

My question is a Java newbie question, what's the signature of a class which isn't packaged?

Comment: The JNI signature of anything is as per the output of the `javah` tool. You should not consider trying to figure it out yourself for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `YourClass` is a class in default package then the fully qualified name is simply `YourClass`.

If the Java method is

```
public void method(YourClass x);
```

then you can search the method via:

```
jmethodID m = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, javaclass, "method", "(LYourClass;)V");
```

The tool `javah` may generate an *.h file where you can see the method signature.

The fully qualified name can be easily printed from java

```
System.out.println(instanceOfYourClass.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a bunch of question, It's for accessing a method from an object field of another type, does it works? What's the meaning of the "V"? I think I've seen different kind of signatures (without the "V" and parenthesis) other the web are there other or is signatures for older version of JNI?

Comment: `(LYourClass;)V` is signature for method with one parameter with type YourClass and returning void. Anothe example is `(B)I` - it method with parameter boolean returning int. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815284

Comment: Ok but I want to access to a parameter of an object and not a method, does `jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, myClass, "theField", "LClassname");`  followed by `jobject myObj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, jobjectContainer, fid);` works ?